# rails understanding sql code to write tests

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to figure out what is checked with this method and then I will test according to this.

**partner.rb**

```
def get_record_count
    self.administrator? ? ContactRecord.where("partner_id in ( SELECT id FROM partners WHERE company_id = ? )",self.company_id).size : self.contact_record.size
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
SELECT id FROM partners WHERE company_id = ?
```

This part returns list of ids of "partners" with company_id = id of current Object (Model). Name this list as PARTNERS_LIST

2.

```
ContactRecord.where("partner_id in ( SELECT id FROM partners WHERE company_id = ? )",self.company_id)
```

And this part finds ContactRecords with "partner_id" belongs to PARTNERS_LIST.

3.

```
self.administrator? ? ContactRecord.where("partner_id in ( SELECT id FROM partners WHERE company_id = ? )",self.company_id).size
```

Finally this returns count of ContactRecords, finded at stage 2.

Answer (score 1):

If `that partner` is an administrator then it matches it's `company_id` with fellow `partners`. Then it retrieves associated `ContactRecords` where `partner_id = fellow ids` and return back the size of total such records : number of matched contact records.

If it is not an administrator, it gives back it's `contact_record.size`

**ActiveRecord substitute** for:
`ContactRecord.where("partner_id in ( SELECT id FROM partners WHERE company_id = ?)", self.company_id).size`

`ContactRecord.where(:partner_id => Partner.where(:partner_id => self.company_id).pluck(:id)).size`